# How do I determine what JRE Mongo Compass is using on Windows 10?

Tags: java, windows-10, keystore, mongodb-compass

I'm using Mongo Compass 1.29.6 on Windows 10.  It is installed to this directory

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass
```

I would like to figure out what JRE Mongo Compass is using because I want to add some trusted certificates to the key store.  However, I cannot find a JRE within the above directory.  The child directories are

```
locales
swiftshader
resources
```

I have a $JAVA_HOME environment variable set on my system.  Would it be getting its JRE from there?